# How to get the component's return value

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I have some code like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const t = () => ["test1", "test2"];
const Translate = () => t("myText");

const MyComponent = ({ children }) => {
  console.log(children);
  return (
    children &&
    typeof children === "object" &&
    Array.isArray(children) &&
    children.map(val => (
      <>
        {`${val}__attached`}
        <br />
      </>
    ))
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyComponent>
        <Translate />
      </MyComponent>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I check the console, I get a React element printed. But I want its return value.

For example, if I replace this code:

```
    <MyComponent>
        <Translate />
    </MyComponent>
```

with

```
    <MyComponent>
        {t()}
    </MyComponent>
```

Then I get an array with 2 objects printed on console. I want to see this same output in my first case.

I want it, because I want to loop through the values returned by `Translate` and generate output based on that.

Thank you.

Here is the codesandbox link:

[image: Edit ancient-monad-5y2ur]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve what you want. Indeed, when you write `{t()}` you actually provide an array as a children for `MyComponent` and can therefore `map` its values.

However, as soon as you write `<Translate/>`, children of `MyComponent` is no longer an array but a React Element (HTML element so to speak)  (print `children` in `MyComponent` to check) making your test always false (so it prints nothing)

Try to call `<Translate/>` outside of `MyComponent` and you will see "test1test2" displayed on your page. It is no longer an array.

Instead of writing this:

```
<MyComponent> 
   <Translate />
</MyComponent>
```

I think you should do the other way around to be able to easily manipulate what comes from `Translate` and passing it to `MyComponent`:

```
   <Translate>
      {values => <MyComponent values={values}>} 
   </Translate>
```

with `Translate` being:

```
const Translate = ({ children }) => children(t("myText"));
```

and `MyComponent`:

```
const MyComponent = ({ values }) => {
  return (
    Array.isArray(values) &&
    values.map(val => (
      <>
        {`${val}__attached`}
        <br />
      </>
    ))
  );
};
```

Live demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-swirles-w9kxg)